# Springboot JSP submit form sending data as NULL to MYSQL Database; how do I fix this?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, jsp

It's connected properly to the localhost and database because it will create a table in the database.

But it's just that when I'm on the website UI and input data, it does not go into the MySQL Database (it creates a new row but the data is null other than the "id" column. I suspect either my controller class is wrong, or my JSP forms are wrong (which I've posted as the first two to three code blocks below). What do I fix please? Thanks! (please ignore that some themes in this code make no sense such as hiphop and customer and restaurant; I have merged many codes I've found online while figuring this out)

Customer Controller:

```
package net.codejava.SpringBootWebAppExample.subpack;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class CustomerController {
@Autowired
private CustomerRepository customerRepo;

@GetMapping("/list_contact")
public String listAll(Model model, Breakingst breakingst) {
    List<Breakingst>listHiphop = customerRepo.findAll();
    
    model.addAttribute("hiph", listHiphop);  
    customerRepo.save(breakingst);
    
    return "contact";   
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/submitForm", method = RequestMethod.POST)  
    public String submitForm(@ModelAttribute("hiph")  Breakingst breakingst)  
    {  

        return "confirmation-page";  
    }  

}
```

contact.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>   
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Contact List - Spring Boot Web Application Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 align="center">My Contact List</h1>
    <br/>
  
  <form:form action="submitForm" method = "POST"  modelAttribute = "hiph" >  
          iD: <form:input  path = "${id}"/>         
        <br><br>  
        Name: <form:input  path = "${name}"/>         
        <br><br>  
        Email: <form:input path="${email}" />  
        <br><br>  
        Age: <form:input path = "${age}"/>  
        <br><br> 
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"  />      
    </form:form>  


<br>

<br>
<br>    
</body>
</html>
```

confirmation-page.jsp

```
<%@taglib uri = "http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix = "form"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>   
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html>  
<body>  
<p>Your reservation is confirmed successfully. Please, re-check the details.</p>  

id: ${id }
Name : ${name} <br>  
Email : ${email}  
Country : ${country}  

<br>
<br>
</body>  
</html>
```

Breakingst.java

```
package net.codejava.SpringBootWebAppExample.subpack;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;


@Entity
@Table(name = "newstyles")
public class Breakingst {
        
    //"(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)"originally had this next to @GeneratedValue, but it messed things up
       @Id
       @GeneratedValue
       private Long id; 

       private String name;
       private String email;
       private String age; 
       
       public Breakingst () {
           
       }
       
       public Breakingst (Long id, String name, String email, String age){
           super();
           this.id=id;
           this.name = name;
           this.email =email;
           this.age = age;
       }
       //getters and setters removed to save space
}
```

CustomerRepository.java (interface)

```
package net.codejava.SpringBootWebAppExample.subpack;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<Breakingst, Long>{

}
```

SpringBootWebAppExampleApplication.java

```
package net.codejava.SpringBootWebAppExample;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.BeanPropertyRowMapper;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;

//imported this to access other package
import net.codejava.SpringBootWebAppExample.subpack.Breakingst;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootWebAppExampleApplication implements CommandLineRunner{

     @Autowired
        private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootWebAppExampleApplication.class, args);
    }
    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM newstyles";
        List<Breakingst> hiphop = jdbcTemplate.query(sql,
                BeanPropertyRowMapper.newInstance(Breakingst.class));
         
        hiphop.forEach(System.out :: println);
        
    }

}
```

This is what th econsole looks like as I submit data in my input form on the website UI (the first four columns in this order are  id, age, email, name):

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        breakingst0_.`id` as id1_0_,
        breakingst0_.`age` as age2_0_,
        breakingst0_.`email` as email3_0_,
        breakingst0_.`name` as name4_0_ 
    from
        `newstyles` breakingst0_
Hibernate: 
    select
        `next_val` as id_val 
    from
        `hibernate_sequence` for update
            
Hibernate: 
    update
        `hibernate_sequence` 
    set
        `next_val`= ? 
    where
        `next_val`=?
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        `
        newstyles` (
            `age`, `email`, `name`, `id`
        ) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Here is pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>net.codejava</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringBootWebAppExample</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>SpringBootWebAppExample</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        
        
        
        
        <dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.23</version>
    <type>jar</type>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
        <!--   <dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>  -->
        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
</dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>



        

<dependency>
    <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
    <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.2</version>
</dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jstl/jstl -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>jstl</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
        
        
        
        
        <!-- when I added these next two dependencies from step4, then all the 3 other classes hopped into the SpringBootWebAppExample folder too; it used to not be there; it made it work with the JSP; step 4 exaplins it   -->
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        
        
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

application.properties

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/BREAKDANCE5000
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root

spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=true
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>My Contacts - Spring Boot Web Application Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>My Contacts</h1>
    <a href="/list_contact">Click here to list all contacts</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your form is sending the data and submitForm is binding that data to the breakingst object and then returning to the confirmation-page.jsp. But in this flow save method to actually save the object to the data is never called, so how will this show it in the database.
You should add **customerRepo.save(breakingst);** in the submitForm method.

Comment: I think this is a step in the right direction, but there still needs to be a few more changes for it to work. 

I tried and it didn't work. Anything else we can use to build on top of your suggestion?

Comment: Nevermind. I've figured it out. There was a few other things I had to do but yours was definitely a very important step. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You must add Breakingst as @RequestBody to the submitForm method.  Then     customerRepo.save(breakingst);

OR

You can write a service class and create a save method inside it, then call it from the controller and use it.

CustomerRepository customerRepository;

public void save(Breakingst breakingst){

```
customerRepository.save(breakingst);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, there are some configurations in which you cannot send data to your database without getting null using postman or insomnia in forms, you must pass through the frontend. You have to check if you call your repository class in the controller. Then you can figure out what you are trying to achieve and how to achieve it. For instance, you can only save value here through frontend:

service interface:

```
public interface EmployeeService {

 void saveEmployee(Employee employee);

}
```

service impl:

```
@Service

public class EmployeeServiceImpl implements EmployeeService{

 @Autowired

    EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;

@Override

    public void saveEmployee(Employee employee) {

        this.employeeRepository.save(employee);

    }

}
```

controller class:

```
 @PostMapping("/saveEmployee")

    public String saveEmployee(@ModelAttribute("employee") Employee employee){
        employeeService.saveEmployee(employee);

        return "redirect:/homepage";

    }

}
```

with this code, you can only add value through the frontend